# Jquery click event after after creating div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

hello people here is my ajax output...

```
$(function(){
    //after ajax request
    success:function(data){
        $('#inbox').html('<div class="inbox_user"  id='+data+'>'+data+'</div><br>')
    }
})
```

Div is creating successfully,so Iam very sure no issues with ajax code....but now i have to give `click event` to class `.inbox_user` ,,,its not working with no error message on console... click event for `#inbox` works fine.....  any idea to fix this??

i am trying in normal way `$('.inbox_user').click(function(){})`

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Comment: use delegate for that

Comment: I have  tried the normal way....$('.inbox_user').click(function(){})

Comment: try this $(.inbox_user).live('click', function(){} );

Comment: try like this $(document).on('click',".inbox_user" function(){} );

Comment: @i'mPosSible I think that wont work

Answer (score 2):

try this :-

```
$(document).on('click', '.inbox_user',function(){
  alert(1);                                                
});
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/shE58/13/)

Comment: yup its working... :)

Comment: Yup, this is right. With jQuery we used to use the 'live' bind event which checks for new elements after the DOM has loaded, however now 'on' handles this fine in the newer versions.